# send list value from django template to the django view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a code written which dynamically add a list when the user clicks on the add button.
 for eg two lists are created-

```
      <ul>
         <li>samsung galaxy</li>
          <li>xiaomi redmi note 5</li>
      </ul>
```

code of frontend for adding li

```
<div class="compare_val"> <input type="text" id="txtVal" placeholder="write 
 to add">
      <button onclick="addLi()" class="btn">Add</button></div>
       <ul id="list">
       <li>{{ Brand }}</li>
    </ul>
    <button id="Com_action" class="btn btn-danger ml-3" 
  onclick="ComAction()">Compare</button>

    <script>
       function addLi()
        {

            var txtVal = document.getElementById('txtVal').value,
                listNode = document.getElementById('list'),
                liNode = document.createElement("LI"),
                txtNode = document.createTextNode(txtVal);

                liNode.appendChild(txtNode);
                listNode.appendChild(liNode);
        }
    </script>
```

now I want to send the li data as a list

`['samsung galaxy', 'xiaomi redmi note 5']` to the view

when the user clicks on the compare button.

please help me to achieve this.

[image: image of html page]

Comment: Please provide frontend code - how add is working? Do you use any framework / jquery?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to modify your scripts to include `csrfmiddlewaretoken` and send data using `XmlHttpRequest` (I'm assuming you are not using `jquery`):

```
<script>
    // Standard django function to get csrf_token. More info:
    // https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/#acquiring-the-token-if-csrf-use-sessions-and-csrf-cookie-httponly-are-false
    function getCookie(name) {
        let cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                let cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }

    const listNode = document.getElementById('list');
    let brands = [];

    function addLi() {
        let txtVal = document.getElementById('txtVal').value,
            liNode = document.createElement("LI"),
            txtNode = document.createTextNode(txtVal);

        liNode.appendChild(txtNode);
        listNode.appendChild(liNode);

        // Save newly added brand to array
        brands.push(txtVal);
    }

    function ComAction() {
        // Prepare AJAX request
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
            data = new FormData();

        // Add token
        data.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', getCookie('csrftoken'));

        // Add all brands
        brands.forEach(function (brand) {
            data.append('brand', brand);
        });

        // We are sending it via POST request to url '/'
        xhr.open('POST', '/', true);
        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                alert('Data received successfully. Brands are ' + xhr.responseText);
            } else if (xhr.status !== 200) {
                alert('Request failed.');
            }
        };
        // Actually send request
        xhr.send(data);
    }
</script>
```

Your django endpoint can process brands like this:

views.py:

```py
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        brands = request.POST.getlist('brand')
        return HttpResponse(", ".join(brands))
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

If you want django to send data and redirect user, modify script:

```
// ...
xhr.open('POST', '/', true);
xhr.onload = function () {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                alert('Data received successfully. Brands are ' + data.brands);
                window.location.replace(data.redirect_url);
            } else if (xhr.status !== 200) {
                alert('Request failed.');
            }
        };
xhr.send(data);
```

and django:

views.py:

```py
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        brands = request.POST.getlist('brand')
        response_data = {
            'brands': brands,
            'redirect_url': '/new_url'
        }
        return JsonResponse(response_data)
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Comment: thank you so much..... it's working but I want to send some context data as parameter..redirect() fun is not supporting parameters

Comment: You want to send some data from django to frontend **and** redirect it? It will lose your parameters once it is redirected, unless saved in cookies/storage. But sure that can be done.

Comment: @souravkukreti I've updated the answer. Django is sending both brands and url in dict, encoded in json. Frontend will show brands and afterwards will redirect user to new url.

Comment: in console im getting syntax error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ComAction.xhr.onload

Comment: You are either not sending JSON or not receiving it correctly. Update your question with current code. I'm sure it is working since I checked it locally.

Comment: I comparing the phones..so the user will add the products using add button and then click on compare button for comparing the phones. now the products name fir go to the view..and I have written code for scraping the data on the basis of product name and it will save the products specifications as a dictionary. now what I want.. I want to redirect to the comapre_in.html page with the dictionary as a parameter where the user can see the comparison table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193190/discussion-between-gasanov-and-sourav-kukreti).

Comment: problem is not solved.  can not display data in template

Answer (score 0):

First get the list -

```
var lis = document.getElementById("selectedli").getElementsByTagName("li");
```

now store them to an input -

```
<input name="id_selected" type="text" hidden>
```

Now, you can't pass the array directly, Use `jQuery.param(yourObject)`.

```
document.getElementById("id_selected").value = jQuery.param(lis)
```

The param() method creates a serialized representation of an array or an object that can be understandable by various frameworks like php, ruby, django etc.

For again converting it to python

```
from urllib import parse
value = parse.parse_qs(self.request.POST.get('name'))
```

If you want to use ajax you can. This code is not tested by me, so report if any error occurs.

Comment: I had done with the help of  Ajax... but using Ajax in view it does not render/redirecting me to the different page after performing the task on the list's data

Comment: you can simply get the success redirect url form view and then in ajax redirect if success say - `success: function(data){ window.location.replace(data.success_url);}`

Comment: when redirecting there is a dictionary which I want to send to the template where I'm redirecting

Comment: you can't post data when redirecting, the only thing you can do is make serialized representation of an dictionary (`jQuery.param(yourObject)`) and pass it in url

Comment: value = parse.parse_qs(self.request.POST.get('name')) self is Unresolved reference